# Background passing array instead of object

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

How can I pass an array to defaults instead of an object?

```
func appMovedToBackground() {
    print("App moved to background!")

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    defaults.setObject(names, forKey: "names")
}
```

Comment: an NSArray is an acceptable value for the first parameter. What is the type of `names` in your example?

Answer (score 0):

The acceptable types for NSUserDefaults are these ,says class reference.

> The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

Is your `names` an NSArray or a swift Array? Therein lies the answer.